# PayPal DoDirectPayment working without cvv

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

Hi I implement PayPal DoDirectPayment in my website, I want to required expire date And CVV but payment taking without those with this warning "This transaction was approved. However, the Card Security Code provided had too few, too many, or invalid character types but, as per your account option settings, was not required in the approval process"

I'm using PHP.

My Code is

```
$api_endpoint = 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp';
$request = array
            (
                'METHOD'                => 'DoDirectPayment',
                'USER'                  => 'sell3_api1.pay.com',
                'PWD'                       => '75DQHCABLDFSDF',
                'SIGNATURE'         => 'AFcWxV21C7fd0asdasdCpasdsdAtxzafSFsaKZ3unSUBjX9r-',
                'VERSION'               => '55.0',
                'PAYMENTACTION' => 'Sale',
                'FIRSTNAME'         => $current_user->user_login,
                'LASTNAME'          => '.',
                'IPADDRESS'         => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
                'ACCT'                  => $acct,
                'CREDITCARDTYPE'=> 
                'EXPDATE'               => $month.$year,
                'CVV2'                  => $cvv,
                'AMT'                       => $amt,
                'CURRENCYCODE'  => 'USD',
            );

    $nvp_string = '';

    foreach ($request as $key => $value) {
        $nvp_string .= '&'.$key.'='.urlencode($value);
    }

    $curl = curl_init();
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $api_endpoint);
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvp_string);

    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    parse_str($result);
```

How can I solve It.

Comment: I hope you run this app in testing environment, otherwise you wcould get into lot of trouble really fast

Comment: Sorry I didn't get what you want to say.

Comment: If you have this live on a web and take payments without cvv, it is only matter of time before people with stolen cards funnel huge amount of money through your portal

Comment: So what should I do @ The Law

Comment: @Mamunur Rashid, Try with enabling "Negative Testing" mode. follow this to enable it. https://docs.adyen.com/developers/paypal-integration-manual